# Python RQ AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute '__module__'

Tags: python, django, redis

I'm trying to enqueue a basic job in redis using [django_rq](https://github.com/ui/django-rq), a python library for queueing jobs and processing them in the background with workers, but the simple call throws a:

```
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute '__module__'
```

I've traced down the issue to this [line](https://github.com/nvie/rq/blob/f39949eeded28d32e03482b80995521cfe5531bd/rq/queue.py#L187-189) in the [rq](https://github.com/nvie/rq) library:

```
 if not isinstance(f, string_types) and f.__module__ == '__main__':
            raise ValueError('Functions from the __main__ module cannot be processed '
                             'by workers.')
```

I'm passing a function in as `f` so I dont understand how it can throw an attribute error on a `dict`. Any ideas on whats going wrong?

Stack Trace:

```
  File "/Users/admin/dev/feedme-web/feedme/api/views.py", line 133, in post
    parameter_dict = {
  File "/Users/admin/dev/feedme-web/feedme-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_rq/queues.py", line 162, in enqueue
    return get_queue().enqueue(func, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/admin/dev/feedme-web/feedme-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rq/queue.py", line 159, in enqueue
    if not isinstance(f, string_types) and f.__module__ == '__main__':
```

Function being enqueued:

```
def create_order_ordrin(user, card_primary_key, address_primary_key):
    parameter_dict = {
      """... pararmeters for call here ..."""
    }
    ordrin = initialize_ordrin()
    return ordrin.order_user(**parameter_dict)
```

`*` note the values user, card_primary_key, and address_primary_key are not being used yet

Comment: Are you sure you didn't accidentally **call** the function and are passing in the dictionary returned by the function?

Comment: @MartijnPieters you're right, thats exactly whats happening. but how can I enqueue the function with the proper parameters with out calling it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are calling the function and passing in the **result** of the function call to the queue.

Register the function without calling it, and include the arguments to be passed when it *is* to be called:

```
django_rq.enqueue(create_order_ordrin, foo, bar=baz)
```

and it'll be called as `create_order_ordrin(foo, bar=baz)`.

Comment: your a champ; this works great. I've read through that part of the docs many times, but I kept using `django_rq.enqueue(create_order_ordrin(), foo, bar=baz)`. thanks for setting me straight on those `()`.